# TCP routing with Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to do routing using Nginx via TCP layer. 
I have multiple different databases where I need to perform routing from API to them base on rule or the request that is received by the API

```
+++++       +++++++++++++     +++++++--------> mysqlServer(managerDb)
+API+ ----->+MySQLClient+---->+Nginx+--------> mysqlServer(customerDb)
+++++       +++++++++++++     +++++++--------> mysqlServer(........Db)
```

I already did the typical one with load balancing but I want it to be routed based on the request

thanks

Comment: That just seems wrong. What is the reason you want to use a *web* server to do low-level TCP routing? Or do you mean HTTP redirection or something similar?

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know it seems wired, but I do find it helpful for my case, nginx already do load balancing in the TCP layer. However, it sticks me with their own balancing logarithms.

Comment: Rob thanks, I am asking for documentation only, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx mainly works at layer 7 ([application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)), what you need is something at layer 4 (transport) for this [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) could better help to achieve what you need since it can do both HTTP and TCP ([db load balancing with HAProxy example](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/howtos/haproxy.html))

Probably by using Nginx plus you could also do the same, check this article regarding how to do [layer 4 load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/layer-4-load-balancing/).

Also look at [TCP and UDP load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/) with requires the latest open source Nginx built with the `--with-stream` configuration flag.

[image]

Here an article explaining how to do load balancing with HAProxy